# Network indicator missing in ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: networking, 14.04, 64-bit, network-manager

Network indicator is been missing from top right corner panel in  Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
When I run #sudo nm-applet

nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon.

Already have tried these following steps without success.

Restart Unity panel service with #killall unity-panel-service.
Reinstalled my network-manager network-manager-gnome.

My /etc/network/interfaces only contains the following:

```
auto lo iface
lo inet loopback
```

Please let me know how I can bring back my network indicator. #no solution yet

Comment: Any1 here to help?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete` did the trick for me.

Comment: work for me 15.04